# Return custom Outlook property value

Tags: vba, outlook

Background: Working on a project to pull information from Outlook emails into an Excel sheet using VBA.

Problem: I'm able to get all of the values but Ticket Number. The ticket number is a custom column heading we created.

Code source: https://www.encodedna.com/excel/how-to-parse-outlook-emails-and-show-in-excel-worksheet-using-vba.htm

```vb
For Each objItem In myFolder.Items
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            
        Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set objMail = objItem
    
        Cells(iRows, 1) = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
        Cells(iRows, 2) = objMail.Subject
        Cells(iRows, 3) = objMail.ReceivedTime
        Cells(iRows, 4) = objMail.body
        Cells(iRows, 5) = objMail.Categories
        Cells(iRows, 6) = objMail.ticketnumber
    End If
    iRows = iRows + 1
Next
```

Variations I tried:

```
ObjectMail.ticketnumber
ObjectMail.TicketNumber
ObjectMail.ticket_Number
```

Comment: Exactly how was the custom column created?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
objMail.ItemProperties("TicketNumber").Value
```

Overview of ItemProperties/UserProperties:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/navigation/properties-overview

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking in the [UserProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.userproperties) collection. The corresponding property returns the `UserProperties` collection that represents all the user properties for the Outlook item. The [UserProperties.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.find) method locates and returns a `UserProperty` object for the requested property name, if it exists. Here is what MSDN states:

> If you use Find to look for a custom property and the call succeeds, it returns a UserProperty object. If it fails, it returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic).

If you use Find to look for a built-in property, specify False for the Custom parameter. If the call succeeds, it returns the property as a UserProperty object. If the call fails, it returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic). If you specify True for Custom, the call does not find the built-in property and returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic).

Also you may check the transport message headers to make sure such property exists (`PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS`):

```
propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
```