# How to return Outlook email custom property?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to pull information from Outlook into an Excel spreadsheet using VBA.

I cannot pull the ticket number column data. The ticket number is a user-defined field.

Outlook email columns:
[image]

Excel spreadsheet:
[image]

```
For Each objItem In myFolder.Items


        Set objMail = objItem

        Cells(iRows, 1) = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
        Cells(iRows, 2) = objMail.Subject
        Cells(iRows, 3) = objMail.ReceivedTime
        Cells(iRows, 4) = objMail.body
        Cells(iRows, 5) = objMail.Categories
        Cells(iRows, 6) = objMail.ItemProperties("Ticket Number").Value
         
         

        inc = inc + 1
         
    End If
    
    iRows = iRows + 1
```

Comment: What happens when you try that?  Are you filtering out non-mail items so you're not trying to access that custom property on (eg) a calendar item?

Comment: Also - you have not responded to any of the replies on your previous post on this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243916/parse-outlook-custom-heading-to-excel-vba

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse outlook custom heading to excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243916/parse-outlook-custom-heading-to-excel-vba)

Comment: I got it to work thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Outlook folders may contain different item types - mails, appointments, documents and etc. So, in the loop you need to check whether you deal with a mail item or not before accessing any `MailItem`-specific properties.

```
For Each objItem In myFolder.Items
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
```

The [MailItem.ItemProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.itemproperties) property returns an `ItemProperties` collection that represents all standard and user-defined properties associated with the Outlook item.

```
 'Create a reference to the email item's properties collection.  
 Set objItems = objMail.ItemProperties
```

So, you can iterate over all items in the collection to make sure the required property exists. So, if you find the property you can then ask for the `Value`.